# Java Android - Fixed footer with listview

Tags: java, android, listview, footer

i want make fixed footer, but I've got a problem.

My activity_main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shppandroid1.app.MainActivity">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ececec"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

If I add here LinearLayout, the app just shows the error. How can I make fixed footer?

Example: http://blog.maxaller.name/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/listview_footer_scrolling.png -> Button "Add Item" - it fixed footer.

Comment: I think good idea will be just add another list item which will be using as footer or below of swiperefresh add layout (below all android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout)

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#0A756E"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_archiv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_archiv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/archiv"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Inside of your code, u have to set the height of the footer as a padding for the listview. Because this is in px and u'll need dp, just transform it:

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int size = (int) (FOOTERHEIGHT * scale + 0.5f);
        SWIPEREFRESHLAYOUT.setPadding(0, 0, 0, size);
```